# NSMetadataQuery doesn't finish gathering (no notification)

Tags: iphone, ios5, icloud, nsmetadataquery

I'm making a backup managrer for my App (via iCloud). I did some tests and the basics worked. But few days later it stopped. I'm using **`NSMetadataQuery`** for searching if backup file exists. My backup files are named e.g. *`Backup29112011154133.xml`* where numbers represent date of the backup (formatted as *`ddMMyyyyHHmmss`*). I check for it in `-viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self checkForRemoteFile];
}

- (void)checkForRemoteFile {
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (ubiq) {
        NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
        [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like 'Backup*'",NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
        [query setPredicate:pred];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];
        [query startQuery];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iCloud is unavailable at the moment" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert setTag:TAG_ALERT_NOICLOUD];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notif {
    NSMetadataQuery *query = [notif object];
    [query disableUpdates];
    [query stopQuery];
    [self loadRemoteFile:query];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];
}

- (void)loadRemoteFile:(NSMetadataQuery *)query {
    if ([query resultCount] == 1) {
        canRestore = YES;
        NSMetadataItem *item = [query resultAtIndex:0];
        // parse the backup file
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        canRestore = NO;
        modifDate = @"never";
        backupInfoLoaded = YES;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

The problem is that `- (void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notif` is never executed. I put breakpints and NSLogs ion there but nothing happend.

I also tried to check for other notifications e.g. 'query did start gathering' and 'query process'. Only 'query did start' notification is posted.

I also have AppID with iCloud registered and entitlements file attached.

Can you help me out what's going on? Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### FIXED by creating `ivar` for `NSMetadataQuery`.

I don't know why the application can't read data without NSMetadataquery ivar.

Comment: if you are using ARC, your NSMetaDataQuery gets deallocated after the scope ends. You need a iVar to retain it

Answer (score 17):

First of all NSMetadataQuery doesn't works if startQuery was called not from the MaintThread.
There is possibility that predicate fails for every path also. 
Following code works for me.

```
NSURL *mobileDocumentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
...
query.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%K like \"%@*\"", [mobileDocumentsDirectoryURL path]], NSMetadataItemPathKey];
[query startQuery];
```

Comment: Yeah, but it worked and suddenly stopped, so I don't think that this is the problem..

Comment: FalconSer, I've tried a query with above predicate and I get an exception. It says cannot parse regex, etc. It should be `@"%K BEGINSWITH %@", NSMetadataItemPathKey, [mobileDocumentsDirectoryURL path]]]` (note there is only one percent , there is no quotes around `%@` and the arguments are in inverted order. If needed use `BEGINGWITH[cd]` instead of `BEGINGWITH`)

Comment: Thank you! I was not calling from the main thread and your answer really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there have been many problems with iCloud and using `NSMetaDataQuery`. To be honest with you the best source as of now for all your iCloud related questions is the Apple Developer Forums. Today Apple released iOS 5.1 beta, and the release notes **STILL** say that NSMetaDataQuery isn't functioning properly. It's extremely frustrating that iCloud still isn't working properly, but sadly there's nothing we can do.

Comment: Is there any other way to work with files on iCloud without using NSMetadataQuery?

Comment: Since the iCloud Documents API has been thru many "reincarnations" since it was released, my knowledge may be a little dated(I've been working exclusively with Core Data, UIManagedDocument), but when I used to load data using NSMetaDataQuery I had to load every file. And no as frustrating as it is the only way to work with iCloud is the use Apples documentation code(NSMetaDataQuery).

Answer (score 1):

This problem still persists.  I have been able to trace it to the following divergence:

- If you limit your search predicate on the query to the name key,

for example

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like[cd] %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, @"*"]
```

then it will work as expected (posting all four query lifecycle notifications).

- If, however, you try either a compound predicate or try to work with the path,

as in

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K BEGINSWITH %@", NSMetadataItemPathKey, [self cloudDocumentsURL].path]
```

OR

```
[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:namePred, pathPred, nil]];
```

Then only the initial notification will be posted.

**I have tried literally hundreds of combinations of these configurable variables in multiple test and intended-for-production apps over the last year and have yet to find a counterexample to this hypothesis.**

Unfortunately, NSMetadataQuery just doesn't work for ubiquitous stores (as of 10.8).

My workaround is to get the raw results from the query and work mostly on a bound NSArrayController which can have its results filtered.  This will mean refactoring away from query.results for most existing code and there is a performance hit (presumably) but it is the only way I have found.  I would love an alternative.